# How to retrieve Listitem(selective columns) Sharepoint Online RestApi using Python

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-rest-api

I possess ClientId and Secret key now to fetch the data from Listitem in Sharepoint Online(Rest Api) usint Python Office365 package.
How to retrieve only selected columns from it?
do I need to generate Bearer token? Sample code would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

See: https://kontext.tech/article/491/load-microsoft-365-sharepoint-list-data-in-python

Use the expand parameter in the REST API endpoint to specify the fields you want to retrieve. Yes you need to generate the Bearer token.

```
# Specify the columns you want to retrieve
columns = 'id,Column1,Column2,Column3'

# Construct the endpoint URL
endpoint = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_id}/items?expand=fields(select={columns})'

# Send the GET request
graph_data = requests.get(endpoint, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}).json()

# Print the SharePoint list items
print("SharePoint list items: %s" % json.dumps(graph_data, indent=2))
```